# Injecting PowerPoint Slide at Specific Index

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

How can I inject a slide into an existing PowerPoint presentation at a specific index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following page on MSDN:

[How to: Insert a New Slide into a Presentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850834.aspx)

For other How-To's for OOXml Presentations, see the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850828.aspx

Comment: Thanks seth for the How-To's link also :)